# Create a new column with the most recent row in groupby when a column value condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a new column that records the most recent/previous `date` value when `obs_occurred`==1 for each person (i.e. `pid`). For example the shift column below is what I want:

```
obs_occurred    pid         date           shift
1.0             10000001    2016-01-06     2016-01-06
1.0             10000001    2016-01-07     2016-01-06
0.0             10000001    2016-01-08     2016-01-07
1.0             10000001    2016-01-09     2016-01-07
1.0             10000001    2016-01-10     2016-01-09
...             ...         ...
```

I can use groupby()[].shift() to create a new column that has the date from the previous row for each pid but how can I add a condition that `obs_occurred`==1?

Comment: Could you add your expected result?  I have questions about what value you want for the first row per group and what value you want for the row where `obs_occurred=0`.

Comment: Hi @Emma! In the example above the column `shift` would be the expected result where each cell takes the most recent date value when obs_occurred==1

Comment: this solves 1/3 of the problem `df['shift'] = df[df.obs_occurred == 1].groupby('pid').date.shift()`.  and can fill first value with `min` perhaps.  But I am not figuring out what to do for `obs_occurred=0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Conditional shift:

At first, I even try to write a recursive function to **shift** until meet the criteria, eventually
a thought struck that this is a good case using `ffill` because it needs the last nearest one.

```
df['modify_date'] = np.where(df['obs_occurred'].shift() == 1, df['date'].shift(1), np.datetime64('NaT'))
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
df.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
df
###
   obs_occurred       pid       date modify_date
0           1.0  10000001 2016-01-06  2016-01-06
1           1.0  10000001 2016-01-07  2016-01-06
2           0.0  10000001 2016-01-08  2016-01-07
3           1.0  10000001 2016-01-09  2016-01-07
4           1.0  10000001 2016-01-10  2016-01-09
```

---

#### Conditional shift within group:

```
df2
###
   obs_occurred       pid       date
0             1  10000001 2016-01-06
1             1  10000001 2016-01-07
2             0  10000001 2016-01-08
3             1  10000001 2016-01-09
4             1  10000001 2016-01-10
5             1  10000002 2016-01-06
6             1  10000002 2016-01-07
7             0  10000002 2016-01-08
8             1  10000002 2016-01-09
9             1  10000002 2016-01-10
```

```
df2['md_idg'] = np.where(df2.groupby('pid')['obs_occurred'].shift() == 1, df2.groupby('pid')['date'].shift(1), np.datetime64('NaT'))
df2['md_idg'] = df2.groupby('pid')['md_idg'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

df2
###
   obs_occurred       pid       date     md_idg
0             1  10000001 2016-01-06 2016-01-06
1             1  10000001 2016-01-07 2016-01-06
2             0  10000001 2016-01-08 2016-01-07
3             1  10000001 2016-01-09 2016-01-07
4             1  10000001 2016-01-10 2016-01-09
5             1  10000002 2016-01-06 2016-01-06
6             1  10000002 2016-01-07 2016-01-06
7             0  10000002 2016-01-08 2016-01-07
8             1  10000002 2016-01-09 2016-01-07
9             1  10000002 2016-01-10 2016-01-09
```

Comment: Thanks @Baron! This looks good! Is it possible to add groupby in? I want to make sure the `modify_date` column is created considering each person as a group

Comment: Yes, just put `groupby()` into `where()`, and modify `NaT` with `groupby()` following by `transform()`, as shown in my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

First, I created a dictionary assigning each pid to the last date when obs_occured is 1

```
max_dates = {index: value for index, value in df[df.obs_occurred == '1'].groupby('pid').date.max().items()}
```

Then add a column by just applying this dictionary to pids

```
df['last_date'] = df.pid.apply(lambda x: max_dates[x])
```

Comment: Thanks @Nuri! I think you got my question wrong. By the last date value when obs_occurred==1, I meant the most previous/recent date value with obs_occurred==1, to the current row/date. NOT THE last date of the person.